# mysql -r -s -N tabbed output: how can I handle line breaks and tabs in the data?

Tags: mysql, bash, mysql-cli

I am writing a batch script that needs to get some log in tab separated format.
Problem is that some of the items in the log contains line breaks (\n) and this make lines that don't adhere to the number of columns I expect. is there any way I can replace or ignore or force mysql to write special chars as \x0a etc?

```
#!bash
mysql --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf --database db -e "SELECT * FROM db.Log ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1,10;" -r -s -N 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it with this output format. You should create a CSV file.

Comment: maybe pipe the output into `sed` and with regex remove the excessive line break

Comment: @Barmer how can I do that?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara I dont think it is doable with regexp with arbitrary data as every row could be a row or just raw data from the last column in the previous raw.

Comment: It helps if you put also original output and the expected output.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara thing is I want it to work with arbitrary outputs from mysql